# How do i make enemy move from top to bottom of screen in unity c#?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to create a 2D space shooter type game using unity, but I can't seem to make the spawned enemies move from the top to the bottom of the screen, I'm actually new to unity and c#, and I can't figure out what is wrong with my code.

Here is my code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class EnemyControl : MonoBehaviour {

float speed;
// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    speed = 2f;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    Vector2 position = new transform.position;

    position = new Vector2(position.x, position.y - speed * Time.deltaTime);

    transform.position = position;

    Vector2 min = Camera.main.ViewportToWorldPoint(new Vector2(0, 0));

    if(transform.position.y < min.y) {
    Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}
```

Comment: let me know if you having any problem . i posted the answer

Comment: i'm having a problem with the DestroyCubes  script, the falling object isn't destroyed after colliding with the destroyer object

Comment: add 2d collider at both object , falling object and with the new object .

Comment: check this out  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YQ7Umjp6R10

Comment: thanks for your help, it worked :)

Answer (score 4):

this is how you should move the object from top to down

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class EnemyControl : MonoBehaviour {
   float speed;

    void Start () {
      speed = 2.0f;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void FixedUpdate () {

    godown();

}

void godown() {
    transform.position += Vector3.down *speed* Time.deltaTime;
}
```

now add another object at your game world you can call it destroyer . place that new object at bottom of the scene .give a falling object a tag name "fallingObject".  and add this script with the new object.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class DestroyCubes : MonoBehaviour
{
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col)
{
    if(col.gameObject.name == "fallingObject")
    {
        Destroy(col.gameObject);
    }
}
}
```

new script name should be "DestroyCubes"